# Древнее название Волги

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Недавно посмотрела передачу, где говорилось, что древнее название Волги - Ра было дано в честь египетского бога Солнца - Ра. Но мне это показалось сомнительным. А что говорит официальная наука?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня глюк или я просто не могу найти аналогичный вопрос, на который я весьма подробно отвечал? Ну как бы то там ни было, повторюсь тезисно.

Версия ошибочна, чтобы не сказать абсурдна.
~1. Фонетика древнеегипетского нам до конца неизвестна, письмо их, как вы знаете, было иероглифическим. То, что мы понимаем под древнегипетскими названиями, на самом деле - реконструкция, вполненная на основании сопостовления переводов древнеегипетсих текстов на языки близлежащих народностей, в основном семитских. При этом, если консонантная часть (согласные) ещё несет в себе какую-то достоверность, то вокализмы расставлены нашими современниками совершенно произвольно, для удобства произношения. Почти наверняка настоящее египетское название отличалось от "РА". 
~2. Во времена Геродота проникновение египетского названия в греческий крайне сомнительно. 
~3. Ещё более сомнительно предположение, что египтяне того периода вообще знали о что-то о существовании Волги. Греки же или какие-то контактирующие с ними народы, конечно, знали или могли о ней знать, но использовать "чужое" название от народа, который там никогда не был - это уже вряд ли. Вариант, что название "занесли" народы, контактировавшие с египтянами раньше греков, я даже не рассматриваю.
~4. Хорошо известно, что топонимы, а гидронимы в особенности, всегда связаны с языком и культурой народов, на территории которых они находятся.

Comment: Вы все разложили по полочкам. По п.4. Скорее всего древнее название Волги (Ра) имеет скифское происхождение: они там жили, они и названия давали, и уж конечно, не в честь египетского бога.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще история приволжских народов уходит корнями в такие глубины времени, что и представить себе трудно. У некоторых исследователей можно прочесть, что предки современных финноугорских народов пришли на берега великой реки, которую мордва называют Рав(Rhav),чуваши Атăл,другие тюрки Итиль, Идель(или похоже на то),черемисы(мари) Волгыдо(Светлая), а русские — Волгой, несколько тысяч лет назад. Когда-то греческий историк Геродот писал о территории, соответствующей нынешним Пензенской, Тамбовской областям. По его мнению, отсюда к северу простиралась страна будинов, отсюда же, по данным современных археологов, начиналась территория так называемых городецких, финноугорских племен, ставших непосредственными предками мордвы и других финноугорских народов Поволжья.

Но вот древние египтяне, скорее всего, ни при чем.

Answer (score 1):

Волга называлась Ра ( лат. Rha) в трудах античных авторов. Предполагают, что первое упоминание о Волге встречается в трудах Геродота (V в. до н. э.), в его рассказе о походе персидского царя Дария на скифов (скифы - племя индо-иранского происхождения). 
Ваш вопрос не совсем лингвистический, здесь требуется основательное знание истории, задавать вопрос нужно и историкам, причем серьезным ученым, а не тем, кто на данной теме спекулирует, делая себе имя.

Answer (score -1):

тупорылые москали сами не разберут что намутили

Comment: Дуй отсюда, @Алекс-L,в Эуропу, к примеру, местные вопросы не по твоим хохляческим мозгам.

Answer (score -2):

Ну что касается древних связей,то не надо их недооценивать..и в сибири находят египетские фибулы и на средней Волге раковины каури..Для кочевника Земля- мала,а для городского- велика..РА-древний термин обозначавшиий РАзделение,гРАницу,РАзРЫв чего либо.,никакого отношения к солнцу не имеющий.ВОЛГА(свободное движение),РА-граница.

Comment: Если вы внимательно проанализируете Русский язык,то убедитесь,что термин-РА и его разновидности:-РО,РЭ,РЪ-употребляются всегда,когда нужно обозначить границу,грань,разрез,разделение чего-либо...Производные от него:приставки-РАС,РАЗ,..корни-РАВ,РЫВ,РОВ.

Comment: Есть такой "термин"? Вот уж не знал.  
Зато легко убедиться, что когда надо обосновать "жареный факт" всегда "обозначают" что-то совершенно невнятнтое. Ну "типо таво", что когда надо обозначить чтото0то неприличное, анализируют букву ДУ: дуб, дурак, дупло, сундук (далее - везде).